# Rewrite url and serve file with such filename nginx

Tags: regex, nginx, rewrite

I have a strange task and I have no idea can I do it or not.

1. Nginx gets request by url
2. Nginx must remove from url characters by regex
3. And Nginx must serve file with that name

For example:

Request `/post/some-title/example-title`

And Nginx must serve file with name `postsometitleexampletitle`

I guess I should do it with rewrite and try_files, but I don't know how can I pass rewritten url to serve file with that name.

Can I do it in common?

Comment: So are you trying to strip `/` and `-` from URIs that begin with `/post/` and contain exactly three path elements?

Comment: Yes. I need to remove characters which cannot be used in filename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove characters recursively. For example:

```
location /post/ {
    rewrite ^(/post/.*)[-/](.*)$ $1$2 last;
    rewrite ^(/post)/(.*)$ $1$2 last;
}
```

The first rewrite will loop up to 10 times or until all of the `-` and `/` characters are removed (except the one following `/post` - so that the `location` block is continually re-entered). The second `rewrite` makes the final transformation, which is handled by some other `location` block.